# Are all Complex vector spaces Spinor spaces?

Tags: hilbert-space, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors, complex-numbers

I read that [spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) are elements of complex vector space. My question is can all complex vector space can be termed as spinor space, or is there any particular criteria that make some complex vector spaces as spinor spaces? Please give some ideas regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

No, not all complex vector spaces are spinor spaces. A [spin(or) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation) is a [group representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the [spin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $Spin(p,q)$ that is only a [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) (but not a genuine) group representation of the Lie group $SO^+(p,q)$. Physicists are mostly interested in irreducible spin representations and the [Dirac representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor).

By the way, the spinor space need not always be complex, cf. the [Majorana representation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Majorana+spinor).